# Adding @Generated annotation to JAXB generated classes

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, annotations

I am trying to add a `@javax.annotation.Generated` annotation to all my classes generated by JAXB from a XSD.

I am using *maven-jaxb2-plugin* and a *binding.xjb* file to generate the source. I saw that the JAXB plugin *jaxb2-basics-annotate* should do the trick. But all I can find are examples that add annotations to specific classes. Like this one:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="csw/2.0.2/CSW-discovery.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
  <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='GetRecordsType']">
    <annox:annotate>
      <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="GetRecordsType" />
    </annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

How can I do this for each of my generated files? Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are using [highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) If you are also using his [highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin), there is builtin support for this feature. Just add this to the plugin configuration:

```
<configuration>                                 
    <markGenerated>true</markGenerated>
</configuration>
```

Also check [controlling the output](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Controlling-the-Output).

If you are the official jaxb2 plugin, that feature is also builtin

```
<configuration>
    <addGeneratedAnnotation>true</addGeneratedAnnotation>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Note: both of those depend on old `javax.annotation.Generated` annotation which got moved to `javax.annotation.processing.Generated` in java.compiler module in Java 11. If you want to add such annotations you should be using the annox plugin.